# Cambiar pestañas a activas carrousel

Tags: javascript, css

Buenas estoy haciendo un carrousel de forma manual. Me funciona el carrousel de forma correcta, pero tengo arriba unas pestañas que son como los botones de siguiente y atras (en su función) y depende a que pestaña le das tiene que ir a ese slide.

Os muestro código:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {


        // initial slide
        let slide = 1;
    
        // total slides
        let slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slides .testimonio");
        total = slides.length;
    
        // show first side
        showSlide(1);
    
        next = document.querySelector(".btnRight2");
        prev = document.querySelector(".btnLeft2")
    
        /**
         * event next button
         */
        next.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
            evt.preventDefault();
            slide++;
            if (slide > total) { slide = 1; }
            showSlide(slide);
        })
    
        /** 
         * event prev button
         */
        prev.addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
            evt.preventDefault();
            slide--;
            if (slide < 1) { slide = total; }
            showSlide(slide);
        })
    
        /**
         * show slides
         * 
         * @param {number} n 
         * @return {null}
         * 
         */
        function showSlide(n) {
            n--; // decrement 1
            for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
                (i == n) ? slides[n].style.display = "block" : slides[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    
    })
```

```css
.body {
  color: #fff;
}
.hobbies {
    padding: 5% 0px 5%;
    height: 100vh;
}
.tamanoFiltroBio {
    height: 25%;
}
.he80001 {
    margin-top: 22px!important;
    height: 75%;
}
.testimonio {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    box-shadow: 0 0px 9px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 70%);
    animation-delay: .2s;
}
.sombraaBIO {
    margin: 0px;
    box-shadow: 0 0px 9px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 70%);
}
.slides .testimonio {
    animation-name: fade;
    animation-duration: 2.5s;
}

.separaBanner {
    width: 37%;
    height: 100%;
}
.sombraBIO2 {
    box-shadow: 0 2px 17px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 70%);
    position: relative;
}
.separaBanner img {
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    font-family: "object-fit: cover;";
    width: 100%;
}
.bannerTexto {
    width: 63%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #343434;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 27px 63px 43px 43px;
}
.barraBio {
    width: 10%;
    height: 2px;
    background: #eae200;
    margin-bottom: 19px;
}
.testimonio h2 {
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 2.2rem;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.bannerTexto h2 {
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    color: #fff;
}
.testimonio p {
    font-size: 17px;
    margin-top: 56px;
    font-weight: 500;
    width: 89%;
    color: #fff;
}
.bannerTexto p {
    font-weight: 500;
    text-align: justify;
}
.bannerTexto h3 {
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: 31px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    color: #fff;
}
.btnLeft2 {
    position: absolute;
    right: -2.3%;
    color: #333;
    background: #EAE200;
    bottom: 4%;
    box-shadow: 0 0px 9px 0 rgb(234 225 1 / 70%);
    padding: 7px 20px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    transition: .2s ease-in;
}
.btnRight2 {
    position: absolute;
    right: -2.3%;
    color: #333;
    background: #EAE200;
    bottom: 14%;
    box-shadow: 0 0px 9px 0 rgb(234 225 1 / 70%);
    padding: 7px 20px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    transition: .2s ease-in;
}
.filtra-training {
    margin: 34px 0px;
}
.filtra-training a {
    background: inherit;
    color: #333;
    padding: 7px 20px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    font-weight: 500;
    border: solid 1px #fff;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.activado-filtro {
    background: #EAE200!important;
    color: #333!important;
    border: solid 1px #EAE200!important;
    box-shadow: 0 0px 9px 0 rgb(234 225 1 / 70%);
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: inherit!important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<section class="hobbies" id="hobbies">
        <div class="col-12 center he100 espacioModuloHistory">
            <div class="tamanoFiltroBio">
                <div id="txtWaiBioHob">
                    <h2>Hobbies</h2>
                    <p>healthy body creates a healthy mind</p>
                </div>
                
                <div class="filtra-training center" id="filtraWaiHob">
                    <a  class="activado-filtro">Travel</a>
                    <a >Hotels</a>
                    <a >Cooking</a>
                    <a >Life</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="he80001 slides" style="position: relative;">
                <div class="he100 testimonio  animated fadeIn sombraaBIO" style="margin: 0px;">
                    <div class="row he100">
                        <div class="separaBanner animated fadeIn imgSlidBioWai">
                            <img src="https://image.freepik.com/foto-gratis/fondo-mar-playa-vacio_74190-1749.jpg" alt="" class="sombraBIO2">
                        </div>
                        <div class="bannerTexto animated fadeIn bannerTextoAniamte">
                            <div class="animated fadeIn mod1SlidWai">
                                <div class="barraBio"></div>
                                <h2>Travel</h2>
                                <h3>I love being in the mountains</h3>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="animated fadeIn parrafBioSlidWai">
                                <p>My first real taste of foreign travel was on ski trips and I was instantly hooked, not just on skiing but also on realising there was a whole world out there waiting to be discovered. I have always enjoyed trave- lling and this became a definite advantage when I started working in F1. Even after 20 years of life on the road, I still think travelling is one of the most appealing parts of my job.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                </div>


                <div class="he100 testimonio  animated fadeIn sombraaBIO" style="margin: 0px;">
                    <div class="row he100">
                        <div class="separaBanner animated fadeIn imgSlidBioWai">
                            <img src="{{ asset('images/bio/BIO-24.jpg') }}" alt="" class="sombraBIO2">
                        </div>
                        <div class="bannerTexto animated fadeIn bannerTextoAniamte">
                            <div class="animated fadeIn mod1SlidWai">
                                <div class="barraBio"></div>
                                <h2>Hotels</h2>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="animated fadeIn parrafBioSlidWai">
                                <p>The travel in F1 has led into another passion of mine – hotels. With over 200 annual nights on the road, hotels have literally become a second home. Over the past 8 years I’ve gained a new perspective on hotels as I’ve had the chance to work as a consultant on projects in the Middle East and Asia helping hotel owners and operators design their fitness concepts. I have come to realise that hotels are a bit like F1. There is a joke that goes “how do you become a millionaire? Start off as a billionaire and buy an F1 team”. This can also be true in the hotel world.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                </div>

                <div class="he100 testimonio  animated fadeIn sombraaBIO" style="margin: 0px;">
                    <div class="row he100">
                        <div class="separaBanner animated fadeIn imgSlidBioWai">
                            <img src="{{ asset('images/bio/BIO-24.jpg') }}" alt="" class="sombraBIO2">
                        </div>
                        <div class="bannerTexto animated fadeIn bannerTextoAniamte">
                            <div class="animated fadeIn mod1SlidWai">
                                <div class="barraBio"></div>
                                <h2>Cooking</h2>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="animated fadeIn parrafBioSlidWai">
                                <p>I like to be in the kitchen, often experimenting with healthy options, whilst enjoying my red wine, preferably pinot noir!</p>
                                <p>I love to cook! I do not believe in diets, have never counted a calorie in my life and believe that if you eat well 80% of the time and train properly, you can enjoy the other 20% of your life.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                </div>


                <div class="he100 testimonio  animated fadeIn sombraaBIO" style="margin: 0px;">
                    <div class="row he100">
                        <div class="separaBanner animated fadeIn imgSlidBioWai">
                            <img src="{{ asset('images/bio/BIO-24.jpg') }}" alt="" class="sombraBIO2">
                        </div>
                        <div class="bannerTexto animated fadeIn bannerTextoAniamte">
                            <div class="animated fadeIn mod1SlidWai">
                                <div class="barraBio"></div>
                                <h2>Life</h2>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="animated fadeIn parrafBioSlidWai">
                                <p>I share my life with Tea who travels to the majority of the races with me which is great as we are able to have a life together whilst also being able to do the jobs we both love. Most of our life is spent on the road but when at home.</p>
                                <p>I love being in the mountains whether skiing down them, climbing up them or hiking in them. I’m an active guy and I think a healthy body creates a healthy mind. I can often be found in the gym, although any space whether a hotel room or a park can be a gym. I’m a fan of reading books and I love movies.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                </div>
                
                <div class="botonesTesti">
                    <a href="" class="btnLeft2 animated fadeIn botonsTestiBio"><-</a>
                    <a href="" class="btnRight2 animated fadeIn botonsTestiBio">-></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </section>
```

Como decia, las flechas va adelante y atras, pero las pesatañas si pulso en cooking quiero que vaya al slider de cooking, y si voy dandole a las flechas que se active la pestaña correspondiente.

Esto es posible?? Gracias

Comment: y no podrías hacerlo con target¿? es decir un href con un target al id del div o pestaña que quieres que vaya

Comment: No sabria como hacerlo así... De este modo tambien a la vez que damos a las flechas también cambiarian las pestañas? Me mostrarias un ejemplo por favor? @scorpions78

Comment: Bootstrap tiene una opción para _tabs_ y [este ejemplo](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#javascript-behavior) puede servirte para hacer lo que quieres.

Comment: Hola @Triby pero tendria que utilizar las tabs en si, o su programación en JavaScript? No comprendo mucho como utilizar esto para lo que te comento

Comment: Es que entiendo que podria haberlo hecho con tabs, pero entonces las flechas no harian su función no? Puedo utilizar lo que tengo o ya no es valido? @Triby Si pudieras ayudarme te lo agradeceria, lo entrego en dos dias y voy pillado de tiempo

Comment: Se puede hacer con _tabs_ y adaptar las flechas. Dame unos minutos para analizar tu código, creo que no es tan difícil.

Comment: Ufff muchas gracias! mira que no pensar en hacerlo con tabs :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al final, no fue tan complicado, el funcionamiento es similar al de otras preguntas que has realizado y solo se necesita:

- Obtener todos los enlaces
- Recorrer para escuchar clic
- Intercambiar clase activa entre elemento anterior y el que recibió clic
- Usar la posición (index) del enlace y sumar 1 para mostrar el contenedor correspondiente.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {

        // initial slide
        let slide = 1;
    
        // total slides
        let slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slides .testimonio");
        total = slides.length;
    
   
        next = document.querySelector(".btnRight2");
        prev = document.querySelector(".btnLeft2")
    
        /**
         * event next button
         */
        next.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
            evt.preventDefault();
            slide++;
            if (slide > total) { slide = 1; }
            showSlide(slide);
        })
    
        /** 
         * event prev button
         */
        prev.addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
            evt.preventDefault();
            slide--;
            if (slide < 1) { slide = total; }
            showSlide(slide);
        });
        
        // Obtener enlaces
        let links = document.querySelectorAll('#filtraWaiHob a');
        // Recorrer para asignar evento
        links.forEach((link, index) => {
            link.addEventListener('click', e => {
                // Evitar comportamiento normal del evento
                e.preventDefault();
                // Usar index + 1 para mostrar el elemento correspondiente
                showSlide(index + 1);
            });
        });
    
        // Mostrar primer elemento solo después de definir variables
        showSlide(1);

        /**
         * show slides
         * 
         * @param {number} n 
         * @return {null}
         * 
         */
        function showSlide(n) {
            // Actualizar elemento mostrado, o no funcionarán las flechas
            slide = n;
            n--; // decrement 1
            for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
                (i == n) ? slides[n].style.display = "block" : slides[i].style.display = "none";
            }
            // Eliminar clase del enlace activo
            document.querySelector('.activado-filtro').classList.remove('activado-filtro');
            // Asignar clase activa al enlace que corresponde por posición
            links[n].classList.add('activado-filtro');
        }
});
```

```css
.body {
  color: #fff;
}
.hobbies {
    padding: 5% 0px 5%;
    height: 100vh;
}
.tamanoFiltroBio {
    height: 25%;
}
.he80001 {
    margin-top: 22px!important;
    height: 75%;
}
.testimonio {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    box-shadow: 0 0px 9px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 70%);
    animation-delay: .2s;
}
.sombraaBIO {
    margin: 0px;
    box-shadow: 0 0px 9px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 70%);
}
.slides .testimonio {
    animation-name: fade;
    animation-duration: 2.5s;
}

.separaBanner {
    width: 37%;
    height: 100%;
}
.sombraBIO2 {
    box-shadow: 0 2px 17px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 70%);
    position: relative;
}
.separaBanner img {
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    font-family: "object-fit: cover;";
    width: 100%;
}
.bannerTexto {
    width: 63%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #343434;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 27px 63px 43px 43px;
}
.barraBio {
    width: 10%;
    height: 2px;
    background: #eae200;
    margin-bottom: 19px;
}
.testimonio h2 {
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 2.2rem;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.bannerTexto h2 {
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    color: #fff;
}
.testimonio p {
    font-size: 17px;
    margin-top: 56px;
    font-weight: 500;
    width: 89%;
    color: #fff;
}
.bannerTexto p {
    font-weight: 500;
    text-align: justify;
}
.bannerTexto h3 {
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: 31px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    color: #fff;
}
.btnLeft2 {
    position: absolute;
    right: -2.3%;
    color: #333;
    background: #EAE200;
    bottom: 4%;
    box-shadow: 0 0px 9px 0 rgb(234 225 1 / 70%);
    padding: 7px 20px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    transition: .2s ease-in;
}
.btnRight2 {
    position: absolute;
    right: -2.3%;
    color: #333;
    background: #EAE200;
    bottom: 14%;
    box-shadow: 0 0px 9px 0 rgb(234 225 1 / 70%);
    padding: 7px 20px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    transition: .2s ease-in;
}
.filtra-training {
    margin: 34px 0px;
}
.filtra-training a {
    background: inherit;
    color: #333;
    padding: 7px 20px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    font-weight: 500;
    border: solid 1px #fff;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.activado-filtro {
    background: #EAE200!important;
    color: #333!important;
    border: solid 1px #EAE200!important;
    box-shadow: 0 0px 9px 0 rgb(234 225 1 / 70%);
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: inherit!important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<section class="hobbies" id="hobbies">
        <div class="col-12 center he100 espacioModuloHistory">
            <div class="tamanoFiltroBio">
                <div id="txtWaiBioHob">
                    <h2>Hobbies</h2>
                    <p>healthy body creates a healthy mind</p>
                </div>
                
                <div class="filtra-training center" id="filtraWaiHob">
                    <a  class="activado-filtro">Travel</a>
                    <a >Hotels</a>
                    <a >Cooking</a>
                    <a >Life</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="he80001 slides" style="position: relative;">
                <div class="he100 testimonio  animated fadeIn sombraaBIO" style="margin: 0px;">
                    <div class="row he100">
                        <div class="separaBanner animated fadeIn imgSlidBioWai">
                            <img src="https://image.freepik.com/foto-gratis/fondo-mar-playa-vacio_74190-1749.jpg" alt="" class="sombraBIO2">
                        </div>
                        <div class="bannerTexto animated fadeIn bannerTextoAniamte">
                            <div class="animated fadeIn mod1SlidWai">
                                <div class="barraBio"></div>
                                <h2>Travel</h2>
                                <h3>I love being in the mountains</h3>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="animated fadeIn parrafBioSlidWai">
                                <p>My first real taste of foreign travel was on ski trips and I was instantly hooked, not just on skiing but also on realising there was a whole world out there waiting to be discovered. I have always enjoyed trave- lling and this became a definite advantage when I started working in F1. Even after 20 years of life on the road, I still think travelling is one of the most appealing parts of my job.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                </div>


                <div class="he100 testimonio  animated fadeIn sombraaBIO" style="margin: 0px;">
                    <div class="row he100">
                        <div class="separaBanner animated fadeIn imgSlidBioWai">
                            <img src="{{ asset('images/bio/BIO-24.jpg') }}" alt="" class="sombraBIO2">
                        </div>
                        <div class="bannerTexto animated fadeIn bannerTextoAniamte">
                            <div class="animated fadeIn mod1SlidWai">
                                <div class="barraBio"></div>
                                <h2>Hotels</h2>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="animated fadeIn parrafBioSlidWai">
                                <p>The travel in F1 has led into another passion of mine – hotels. With over 200 annual nights on the road, hotels have literally become a second home. Over the past 8 years I’ve gained a new perspective on hotels as I’ve had the chance to work as a consultant on projects in the Middle East and Asia helping hotel owners and operators design their fitness concepts. I have come to realise that hotels are a bit like F1. There is a joke that goes “how do you become a millionaire? Start off as a billionaire and buy an F1 team”. This can also be true in the hotel world.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                </div>

                <div class="he100 testimonio  animated fadeIn sombraaBIO" style="margin: 0px;">
                    <div class="row he100">
                        <div class="separaBanner animated fadeIn imgSlidBioWai">
                            <img src="{{ asset('images/bio/BIO-24.jpg') }}" alt="" class="sombraBIO2">
                        </div>
                        <div class="bannerTexto animated fadeIn bannerTextoAniamte">
                            <div class="animated fadeIn mod1SlidWai">
                                <div class="barraBio"></div>
                                <h2>Cooking</h2>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="animated fadeIn parrafBioSlidWai">
                                <p>I like to be in the kitchen, often experimenting with healthy options, whilst enjoying my red wine, preferably pinot noir!</p>
                                <p>I love to cook! I do not believe in diets, have never counted a calorie in my life and believe that if you eat well 80% of the time and train properly, you can enjoy the other 20% of your life.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                </div>


                <div class="he100 testimonio  animated fadeIn sombraaBIO" style="margin: 0px;">
                    <div class="row he100">
                        <div class="separaBanner animated fadeIn imgSlidBioWai">
                            <img src="{{ asset('images/bio/BIO-24.jpg') }}" alt="" class="sombraBIO2">
                        </div>
                        <div class="bannerTexto animated fadeIn bannerTextoAniamte">
                            <div class="animated fadeIn mod1SlidWai">
                                <div class="barraBio"></div>
                                <h2>Life</h2>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="animated fadeIn parrafBioSlidWai">
                                <p>I share my life with Tea who travels to the majority of the races with me which is great as we are able to have a life together whilst also being able to do the jobs we both love. Most of our life is spent on the road but when at home.</p>
                                <p>I love being in the mountains whether skiing down them, climbing up them or hiking in them. I’m an active guy and I think a healthy body creates a healthy mind. I can often be found in the gym, although any space whether a hotel room or a park can be a gym. I’m a fan of reading books and I love movies.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                </div>
                
                <div class="botonesTesti">
                    <a href="" class="btnLeft2 animated fadeIn botonsTestiBio"><-</a>
                    <a href="" class="btnRight2 animated fadeIn botonsTestiBio">-></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Es que no llego a comprender bien como funcionan los sliders. De todos modos tengo dos preguntas @Triby . La primera es que si le voy dando con las flechas puede seleccionarse arriba el que se está visualizando? Si no recuerdo mal lo ponia en la pregunta. Y la segundo es si con las pestañas voy a Hotels y seguido gasto la flecha no hace el siguiente como toca. Gracias!

Comment: No había leído ni considerado que las flechas también deben modificar enlaces y ahora se hace al momento de mostrar el elemento.

Comment: Si te pudiera dar 1000 puntos te los daba ahora mismo! madre mia ¡Brillante! funciona de forma perfecta, gracias como siempre @Triby ahora voy a publicar otro slider que es el último que me queda, por si te animas! Gracias! ;)